# My Hyper-V vEthernet (Default Switch) is automatically deleted and re-created every few seconds

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, network-adapter, windows-10-1809

On Windows 10 Pro 1809 build 17763.805 my network connectivity bounces every 2 seconds from online to offline. I'm running Hyper-V in order to use Docker Desktop for Windows.

Checking `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` I see two network interfaces:

- “Ethernet” whose status swaps between my Windows Domain name and “Enabled”
- “vEthernet (DockerNAT)” Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2 (status "Unidentified network")

And then a third that appears and disappears every few seconds:

- “vEthernet (Default Switch)” Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter

When the Default Switch disappears, my Ethernet adapter reports a Windows Domain connection. A few seconds later, when the `Default Switch` reappears, my Ethernet adapter’s status reverts to “Enabled” and I lose a Domain connection while it tries to reestablish a connection.

Digging further, I see this Windows System Event Log block cycle every minute or so (the NIC identifier changes across cycles):

> NIC B99A4A01-143A-4DD6-AE3C-5D6AAA8ABF41 successfully disconnected from port .
>
> The operation 'Delete' succeeded on nic B99A4A01-143A-4DD6-AE3C-5D6AAA8ABF41 (Friendly Name: Default Switch).
>
> NIC C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444 successfully disconnected from port C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444.
>
> The operation 'Delete' succeeded on nic C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444 (Friendly Name: Default Switch).
>
> The operation 'Create' succeeded on nic C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444 (Friendly Name: Default Switch).
>
> NIC C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444 (Friendly Name: Default Switch) successfully connected to port C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444 (Friendly Name: Default Switch) on switch C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444(Friendly Name: Default Switch).
>
> Switch C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444 (Friendly Name: Default Switch) successfully initialized.

I initially posted this to the [Docker forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/vethernet-hyper-v-virtual-adapter-default-switch-bounces-endlessly/83224).

I'm unsure what more could assist diagnosis, so please comment and I'll be happy to add any other useful details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frustratingly, for myself and my colleagues sharing this problem: the solution was to update Windows 10 to 1909 (specifically, I'm on build 18363.476).

An unsatisfactory solution but the only thing that worked after several months of trying.

Comment: Having the same problem here (came from another problem to this because I noticed network interruptions every few 30 seconds or so to my machine). Thanks for reporting this answer. It helped.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem for a long time over several Windows 10 builds but finally found a solution. Currently running Windows 10 build 19025.1052.

There is a service on Windows 10 called "DNS Client" or dnscache that I had disabled. Once I re enabled the service and restarted Windows then Hyper-V created the default switch and it was not removed/reinstalled.

This also fixed issue with WSL 2 install that now uses Hyper-V. WSL 2 install would fail with "The RPC server is unavailable."

To enable the DNS Client service I followed the instructions here:
https://wintechlab.com/enable-disable-dns-client-service/

The service has a high level of permission and the only way I could enable was by going to the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Dnscache
```

and setting `Start` DWORD to 2 (Automatic) instead of 4 (Disabled).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. My DNS Client Service is actually already active. We'll keep digging.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a strikingly similar issue, which materialized right after a reboot, but as I am already updated to the latest version of Windows, the chosen solution was unavailable. Furthermore, the `dnscache` service was already running as mentioned in the OP's comment on Reyad's answer. Eventually, there was a duplicate WSL virtual network, so I knew something was funky.

What *did* end up fixing the issue for me was first running `sfc /scannow`, then stopping and starting the `hns` service (Host Network Service). Then, as I am using WSL 2, I also restarted the `LxssManager` service. After that, the extra WSL network magically disappeared, my connections are stable, and the Event Viewer has shown no new errors.